# Styling DIVs inside Tables

Tags: html, css, width

I am trying to define a weekly calendar, have a table with seven columns (one per day) and 24 rows (one per half an hour):

```css
.cal-week {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cal-week-day {
  width: 14%;
}
.cal-week-hour > td {
  border: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  height: 2.2em;
  position: relative;
}
.cal-week-hour > td > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  background-color: #494C4F;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  border: solid 1px #c8c8c8;
}
.item > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="cal-week" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="cal-week-day">
                monday
            </th>
            <th class="cal-week-day">
                tuesday
            </th>
            <th class="cal-week-day">
                wednesday
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour">
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour">
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="item" width="33.333333333333336%" >
                                        <div>a long description</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="item" width="33.333333333333336%" >
                                        <div>normal desc</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="item" width="33.333333333333336%" >
                                        <div>short</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour">
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour">
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour">
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="item">
                                        <div>asdsad</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using `React`, the percentage of the tds of the inner tables are calculated as `100 / numberOfItems`, in this example since we have 3 items -> 33.333333%. The problem is that the divs can be wider than the tds and as you can see in the fiddler they span over the next column.
The desired output is the following:
[image]

In fact, I have to draw n boxes which have to fit the parent (td) width, which in this case is dynamic. Furthermore, it should be responsive, so I cannot use static widths.

Any hints how to achieve such a result?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan

Comment: Updated my question adding inline demo.

Comment: That inline demo doesn't seem to have got the hang of the word "minimal"

Comment: Reduced the inline demo.

Comment: For an minimal demo you should recreate the program so it only includes code that produces your problem. For example in this code: the text, the dotted lines, the `<a href=#>`, etc.  don't add to the problem. By keeping your question as general as possible it will be easier for other users with a similar question to find a good solution.

Comment: I removed everything not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `.item` class into an `inline-block` element which will fix the 33% width.

Also because the border is added after the 33% width, your item is a bit to wide (it will be 33% + 1px left-border + 1px-right border).
you should consider giving the `.item` class a `box-sizing: border-box;` so the border will be inside this 33% width.

After this you get your desired output. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2burtaz/

I also changed your `min-height` from those `td`'s from 141px to 41px so it looks more like the picture you added.

**-- Can you give me an example using just divs?** question by Emaborsa.

Ofcourse, I would just remove the inner table with all its table elements, also remove the empty div's. And change the `<td>`'s into `<div>`'s. The only thing I have added after this is a `.w-100` class which I added to the outer div so the `33%` width on the inner children works.

```css
.cal-week {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Web (West European)", "Segoe UI", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.cal-week-top {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #444;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cal-week-day {
  width: 14%;
}
.cal-week-day-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.cal-week-weeksel div {
  width: 16px;
}
.cal-week-weeksel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--hover-light);
}
.cal-week-time00 {
  text-align: right;
  border-right: solid 1px #d8d8d8);
  border-left: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
}
.cal-week-hour00 > td,
.cal-week-time {
  border-top: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #d8d8d8;
}
.cal-week-hour30 > td{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
}
.cal-week-time30,
.cal-week-cell {
  border-right: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-left: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  height: 2.2em;
}
.cal-week-cell {
  position: relative;
}
.cal-week-cell > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}
.cal-week-today {
  background-color: var(--button-border-disabled);
}
.item {
  background-color: #494C4F;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
  border: solid 1px #c8c8c8;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item a {
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.item a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.w-100{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="cal-week" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="cal-week-top cal-week-day">
                <div class="cal-week-day-link">26. Dienstag</div>
            </th>
            <th class="cal-week-top cal-week-day">
                <div class="cal-week-day-link">27. Mittwoch</div>
            </th>
            <th class="cal-week-top cal-week-day">
                <div class="cal-week-day-link">28. Donnerstag</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour00">
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour30">
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <div class="item single" title="10:30 - 14:25 Titel (Beschreibung)"  style="min-height: 41px; width: 33.333336%;">
                        <a href="/functionaries/_lists/chapter_events/_pages/disp/6">Titel</a>
                        <div>Beschreibung</div>
                    </div><div class="item single" title="10:30 - 14:25 Titel (Beschreibung)" style="min-height: 41px; width: 33.333336%;">
                        <a href="/functionaries/_lists/chapter_events/_pages/disp/5">Titel</a>
                        <div>Beschreibung</div>
                    </div><div class="item single" title="10:30 - 14:25 Titel (Beschreibung)"  style="min-height: 41px; width: 33.333336%;">
                        <a href="/functionaries/_lists/chapter_events/_pages/disp/4">Titel</a>  
                        <div>Beschreibung</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour00">
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour30">
            <td class="cal-week-time30"/>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-week-hour00">
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="item single" title="12:26 - 13:26 sdsdsd (asdsad)" width="100%" style="min-height: 61px;">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="/functionaries/_lists/chapter_events/_pages/disp/8">sdsdsd</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>asdsad</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cal-week-cell">
                <div/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It might not be the intended way to style inside a table element but I am not sure about this since I never use tables. I would appreciate a reasoning for the -1 tho instead of just a "Nope, -1", so I know what I did wrong and I can do better next time :).

Comment: Can you give an example using just divs?

Comment: @Emaborsa sure, I added it to my answer.